# Necessary condition to extend a morphism of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes

Consider two schemes $X,Y$ over a locally noetherian scheme $S$. Let $p \in X$ and assume that $X$ is irreducible  and *not* affine spectrum of a semilocal ring.

We assume moreover we have a morphism $f: \operatorname{Spec}O_{X,p} \to Y$. One may ask what are the *neccessary* conditions to extend $f$ to an open subscheme $U \subset X$ which contains $p$, that is to extend to a morphism $h: U \to Y$ which restricts under composition with $ \operatorname{Spec}O_{X,p} \to U$ to $f$.

Certainly, a well known *sufficient* condition is if we assume that $Y$ is locally of finite type over $S$. Then we can choose an affine subscheme $\operatorname{Spec} \ R= S_0 \subset S$ and open subscheme $\operatorname{Spec} \ T= Y_0 \subset Y$. Since $Y$ locally of finite type $T= R[x_1,x_2,..., x_n]/I$. Since $R$ is noetherian, $R[x_1,x_2,..., x_n]$ is also noetherian and the ideal $I$ is finitely generated. Let $\operatorname{Spec} \ A\subset X$ be an affine open neighbourhood of $p \in X$.

Then we consider a morphism $\phi:R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_ {X,p}$. Now, write $\phi(x_i)=a_i/r$ for some $r \in A$ not vanishing at $p$ and let $s \in A$ not vanishing at $p$ be such that $s \cdot g(\phi(x_1),\dots,\phi(x_n))=0$ for all $g \in I$. Here it is crucial that $I$ is finitely generated ideal, otherwise such $s$ might not exist. then the open set $D(sf)$ makes the job, where $l:V→Y$ corresponds to the morphism $\psi:k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I\rightarrow A[(sf)^{-1}]$ mapping $x_i$ to $a_i/r$.

Now I ask if to require $Y$ is locally of finite type over $S$ around $y=f(x)$ is also a *neccessary* condition to obtain the extension above. I guess so but I haven't found a conterexample.

Comment: If $X$ is a point then the extension property is vacuously satisfied without any assumptions on $Y$. Do you maybe mean something like "if $Y$ is locally of finite type over $S$ near $y$, then for *every* $S$-scheme $X$ with a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{X,x} \to Y$ taking $x$ to $y$ there exists an extension on an open"?

Comment: No, you are right, I just overlooked this trivial case if $X$ is finite or more general discrete. But, no I not meant the "if $Y$ is locally of finite type over $S$ near $y$, then for every $S$-scheme $X$ with a morphism $Spec \ O_{X,x} \to Y$ taking $x$ to $y$ there exists an extension on an open" since we know that in this case it is always true, see my sketch above. I'm interested in the case if we assume that $X$ is irreducible of dimension $\ge 1$. Is it *neccessary* to require that $Y$ is locally of finite type over $S$ near $y$? I will improve my question...

Comment: In other words I'm asking if the statement that the solubility of the extension problem above (with $X$ irreducible of dim $\ge 1$ is *equivalent* to $Y$ is locally of finite type over $S$ near $y$. One implicaition I solved. For the other I conjecture that it also true but I need a conterexample in order to argue by contraposition

Comment: Oh right, I wrote the converse of what I meant; my question was really about varying $X$. But 'irreducible of dimension $\geq 1$' will not help much, because my objection still exists for (semi)local schemes.

Comment: Yes, I see the issue. The also obvious semilocal case we have also to exclude. see update

Comment: I think you should assume every affine open containing $p$ contains a point which doesn't specialize to $p$ (this is a very mild condition). Then if $Y = \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X, p})$ and $f$ is the identity you obviously can't extend.

Comment: @Johan: This argument I not understand. Assume $X$ affine and contains such point $q$ which doesn't specialize to $p$. That means by definition $q \not \in \overline{\{p\}}$ or equivalently $p$ is not a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{X,q}$. Well, why we *cannot* extend the identity morphism $f:=id: \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X, p}) \to Y:=\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X, p})$? I not understand. If for example $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$ is finite type over $\mathcal{O}_{S, s}$ ($s$ is the image of $p$ by structure map $X \to S$),

Comment: that is $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}= \mathcal{O}_{S, s}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ with finite generated $I$ since $\mathcal{O}_{S, s}$ by assumption Noetherian. That is I see no obstructions to continue the same argument as in fourth paragraph in my question. or do I oversee a detail?

Comment: probably I misunderstood your example, could you explain my thinking error in the previous comments which "propose" that it seems to be possible to extend your morphism?

Comment: The English phrase "q doesn't specializes to p" is equivalent to "p isn't a specialization of q" is equivalent to "p isn't in the closure of q" is equivalent to "q is not a point in the spectrum of the local ring at p".

Comment: @Johan: Sorry for late response. You are right, I confused the $p$ and $q$. But I still not understand why your proposed morphism $f:=id: \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X, p}) \to Y:=\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X, p})$ is not extendable in the sense I explaned above, i.e. to a morphism $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X, p}) \subset U \to Y$? Read again my last comments. Essentially, they tell that if $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$ is finite type over $\mathcal{O}_{S, s}$, then we can argue like in the fourth paragraph of my original question.

Comment: But this construction whould tell that your $f$ *is* extendable, or not? Or does your example contain a detail which makes such argument not applicable here?